# Definition of empty {} after If() statement in eval{} statement

Tags: perl

I am currently attempting to document a Perl script in preparation for converting it to .NET. I have no prior experience in Perl before now, however I was managing to get through it with a lot of Google-fu. I have run into a single line of code that has stopped me as I am unsure of what it does. I've been able to figure out most of it, but I'm missing a piece and I don't know if it's really that important. Here is the line of code:

```
eval { if(defined $timeEnd && defined $timeStart){}; 1 } or next;
```

I know that `defined` is checking the variables `$timeEnd` and `$timeStart` to see if they are `null`/`nothing`/`undef`. I also believe that the `eval` block is being used as a Try/Catch block to trap any exceptions. The line of code is in a `foreach` loop so I believe the `next` keyword will continue on with the next iteration of the `foreach` loop.

The part I'm having difficulty deciphering is the `{};1` bit. My understanding is that the `;` is a statement separator in Perl and since it's not escaped with a backslash, I have no idea what it is doing there. I also don't know what the `{}` means. I presume it has something to do with an array, but it would be an empty array and I don't know if it means something special when it is directly after an `if()` block. Lastly, I no idea what a single integer of `1` means and is doing there at the end of an `eval` block.

If someone could break that line of code down into individual parts and their definitions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Bonus: If you can give me a .NET conversion, and how each Perl  bit relates to it, I will most certainly give you my internet respects. Here's how I would convert it to VB.NET with what I know now:

```vb
For each element in xmlList    'This isn't in the Perl code I posted, but it's the `foreach` loop that the code resides in.
    Try
        If Not IsNothing(timeEnd) AND Not IsNothing(timeStart) then 
        End If
    Catch ex as Exception
        Continue For
    End Try
Next
```

Comment: Where do `$timeStart` and `$timeEnd` come from?

Comment: The {} are part of the syntax of `if`; it just isn't doing anything in the true case.  The semicolon is unnecessary, but it isn't a syntax error since an empty statement is legal so it is separating between the 1 and an empty statement following the if.  Overall, this statement looks buggy or incomplete or both.

Comment: @el.pescado, they are xml nodes from `XML::LibXML`

Comment: Do you `use strict`? How those variables are defined/assigned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignoring `elsif` and `else` clasuses, the syntax of an if statement is the following:

```
if (EXPR) BLOCK
```

The block is executed if the EXPR evaluates to something true. A block consists of a list of statements in curly braces. The `{}` in your code is the block of the `if` statement.

It's perfectly valid for blocks to be empty (to contain a list of zero statements). For example,

```
while (s/\s//) { }
```

is an inefficient way of doing

```
s/\s//g;
```

The thing is, the condition in the following has no side-effects, so it's quite useless:

```
if(defined $timeEnd && defined $timeStart){}
```

It can't even throw an exception!<sup>[1]</sup> So

```
eval { if(defined $timeEnd && defined $timeStart){}; 1 } or next;
```

is equivalent to

```
eval { 1 } or next;
```

which is equivalent to<sup>[2]</sup>

```
1 or next;
```

which is equivalent to

```
# Nothing to see here...
```

---

1. Technically, it can if the variables are magical.

   ```
   $ perl -MTie::Scalar -e'
      our @ISA = "Tie::StdScalar";
      tie(my $x, __PACKAGE__);
      sub FETCH { die }
      defined($x)
   '
   Died at -e line 4.
   ```

   I doubt the intent is to check for this.
2. Technically, it also clears `$@`.

Comment: As for the semi-colon, it's a superfluous empty statement. For example, `perl -E'$_="abc";;;;;;say'` is a weird way of writing `perl -E'$_="abc";say'`.

Answer (score 2):

`eval{}` returns result of last expresion (1 in your example) or `undef` if there was an exception. You can write same code as,

```
my $ok = eval {
  if (defined $timeEnd && defined $timeStart){};
  1 
};
$ok or next;
```

From [`perldoc -f eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)

> .. the value returned is the value of the last expression evaluated inside the mini-program; a return statement may be also used, just as with subroutines.
>
> If there is a syntax error or runtime error, or a die statement is executed, eval returns undef in scalar context or an empty list in list context, and $@ is set to the error message

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. So basically the eval statement is worthless because it will always return a value of 1? Can you elaborate on what the empty `{}` means after the `if()` statement? Finally what does `$ok or next` (in your example) mean in the context of the `foreach` loop that the line of code sits in? Will it always continue to the next iteration of the loop?

Comment: Empty `{}` are just empty block.

Comment: `1` doesn't make `eval` worthless. When `eval` completes successfully, last expression is returned (`1` in that case). If exception is raised, `undef` is returned. So, `1` is to ensure truthful value is returned from `eval` on success.

Comment: Anyway, that `eval` seems redundant, since I see nothing inside that *might* cause exception. Unless, you don't `use strict` (you should `use strict`).

Comment: @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ no, it will return 1 only if there was no exception in `eval{}` code block, so it is a method to track exceptions. `if(..){}` does nothing; it looks like somebody forgot to fill the code in the if block. `$ok or next;` is a way to `continue` inside loop, it is same as `if (!$ok) { next }`.

Comment: @el.pescado if one of the variables was tied, it might throw an exception in FETCH.  But likely the whole statement is just a no-op